# Refetching a previously visited page

Tags: django, mobile-website

All,

I am having a field day with page refetching.  Any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated!!  The behavior is a bit specific to **mobile** browser.

Problem:

I have two pages and created a shortcut link to pg#1 on the home screen.  Through a form submit button, user is taken from pg#1 to pg#2.  All that is working fine.

Now once I am on pg#2. I will leave the browser and click the shortcut later.  The browser will stay on pg#2 and won't go to pg#1 even though the path in URLS is different between the two views.

Update#1:

Here is the code snippets.

```
def sendmsg(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Hello world")
        return redirect ('rcvmsg')
    return render_to_response('sendMsg.html',RequestContext(request))

def rcvmsg(request):
    '''view that receives the msg.'''
    printMsg ='Didnt get a message'
    if messages:
        thisMsg = messages.get_messages(request)
        for rcvMsg in thisMsg:
            printMsg = rcvMsg
    return render_to_response('rcvMsg.html',{'print_msg':printMsg},RequestContext(request))
```

URL:

```
url(r'^rcvMsg/','mydomain.mainApp.views.rcvmsg',name='rcvmsg'),
    (r'^sendMsg/code','mydomain.mainApp.views.sendmsg'),
```

It is almost like Django decides that since I have already visited view#1, it doesn't need to fetch it again.  This problem or behavior **doesn't happen** if I move the same code that handle the two views and the templates to a bare bone test project.

Setup:

I am using django-registration, context session.  I am not using any HTML caching tag.

I already have DEBUG turned on in my settings.py.  Are there other ways that I can tell what the server is doing.

Thanks in advance.

pdxMobile

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was.  I have the form action set back to the view itself in my template.  I guess the browser thinks that since the action is back to the same page and so a reload is unnecessary.

Before:

```
  <form action="." method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
```

Fix:

```
  <form action="./next" method="post"> <--the "next" is fictitious & doesn't exist in URL-->
   {% csrf_token %}
```

Hope this useful for someone someday.

Cheers. -P